# What is the best way to structure a "has many" with a xib element?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a UIViewController that has a ScrollView in it, and I have a separate UIView (not attached to the view controller) that has a text label, and imageView-- it's 200px in height.

Basically I want to instantiate a bunch of the separate UIViews, set their text label and image, and then add them as a subView to the ScrollView.  I am unclear on what the best way to set this up is..  Should my UIView just be a separate UIViewController class, and I should add them as a child view controller?  Or can a UIView class be a .xib's files owner?

Comment: Have you made separate file for your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would (could) do it in the same way that custom UITableViewCells are created from a xib file for UITableViews.

The xib file still has FilesOwner set to the UIViewController that uses it, however the top level element would be a subclass of UIView that you create and customise.

In your UIViewController, instantiate the xib file (using UINib) and then add this to your UIScrollView.

EDIT: A bit more detail:

You have a custom view, MyView and it has a xib file, MyView.xib:

```
@interface MyView : UIView
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@end
```

In the xib file, the top level view is MyView (use cmd-alt-3) and change the class from UIView, to MyView.

Files Owner is set to MyViewController - you can then drag a new referencing outlet from MyView to FilesOwner to link them up.

In UIViewController, you can load MyView.xib with:

```
UINib *myViewNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[myViewNib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
```

and it will populate the UIViewController MyView property: i.e.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MyView *myView;
@end
```

Comment: so what I am confused about is I want a convenient way to access the subviews (label and imageView) in each instance of the UIView to set their properties...  I would need a way to create IBOutlets in a different object in order to easily be able to instantiate these and say instance1.textLabel.text = @"foobar";, etc...

Comment: You can still connect outlets to your custom UIView subclass from interface builder. Usually, you drag and connect them to your UIViewController, but instead, drag them to your UIView class.

Comment: I've added some more details for you above in my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have created a separate class (with .h and .m files) for your view e.g. **Someview**.

**Someview.h**

```
@interface Someview : UIView

@property(strong) UITextField *field;

@end
```

**Someview.m**

```
@interface Someview ()

@end

@implementation Navigator
@synthesize field;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

If you want to add many instances of this view, you just need to add it pragmatically to scrollview.

In your main controller, you can run loop to create many *someView* instances and set postions for them.

Code to follow:

```
Someview *instance = [[Someview alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame];
[scrollview addSubview:instance];
```